# regex patern to find the words from a string

Tags: java, regex

I have a string as follow.

> #a girlfriend, or win an argument,
>
> but
>
> same
>
> # techniques

It should give the output as follow.

> a girlfriend, or win an argument,
>
> techniques

I used the pattern, "#\s*([^#]+$|\w*)" to do this. But it only gives output as

> a
>
> techniques

Please help me.

Below is the code I am using.

```
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#\\s*([^#\n\r]+$|\\w*)");
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
               while (matcher.find()) {
                   System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
/#\W*(.*)/
```

It will ignore all whitespaces after `#` and grab everything after.

Comment: WHat is you result ? I've tested it on http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php and it works for your input.

Comment: `Pattern.compile("#\W*(.*)");`

Answer (score 0):

You could try `(#[^#\n]*\n?)`

Let me know what happens :)

Comment: it did not give me any result. :(

Comment: (#[^#\n]*\n?) try that one instead

Comment: it also does not give the expected result. It only gives me the result as, "#today".

Comment: really? i tried that one http://www.regextester.com/ here on your input and it gave both

Comment: Thanks Chimoo. My code is same as in Ashish's post. The setring I am using is longer instead. I will update with the code.

Comment: Are you entering the string as a multiline string? I assumed that from the OP

Comment: Yes. It is a multi line one taken as a patc from google diff_match_patch library. What is the error I am making here? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Well I ran it using Ashish's code with the string "#a girlfriend, or win an argument,\nbut\nsome\n# techniques" and it worked fine, so it's a problem with the string

Answer (score 0):

Use this pattern '#\s*([^#\n\r]+$|\w*)' and iterate for each match.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("pattern");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("mystring");

    // Find all matches
    while (matcher.find()) {
      // Get the matching string
      String match = matcher.group();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ashish. But this also gives me the result as, "#hi #today".

Answer (score 0):

This is a really helpful site for testing your regex and see what you are going to end up with:
http://myregexp.com/

I think this is what you are looking for #\s*([^#]*|\w*). That $ is what was getting you.

This translates to give me everything after the first #[space] that is not a #. You are not trying to match the second line that starts with a #. You are taking everything after the first # that is not #

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the help.This only gave me the first charter's of each word as, "a t". I don't know whether there is an error in my string. I will check it twice.

Comment: I am not sure why but something is missing from my post it's `#\s*([^#]*|\w*)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code that should work for you:

```
String s = "# hello!";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("#\\W*([^#]*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

It's necessary to use `matcher.group(1)` so that you get just the parenthesized capture group and not the entire expression.